# How can I upload terraform state to s3 bucket?

Tags: terraform

I have a project whose infra is managed by `terraform`. I'd like to push the state to a s3 bucket so other teams can use the state. Below is the backend configuration:

```
terraform {
  backend "s3" {
    bucket = "MY_BUCKET"
    key    = "tfstate"
    region  = "ap-southeast-2"
  }
}
```

when I run `terraform init` I got below error:

```
    AccessDenied: Access Denied
        status code: 403, request id: 107E6007C9C64805, host id: kWASxeq1msxvGPZIKdi+7htg3yncMFxW9PQuXdC8ouwsEHMhx8ZPu6dKGUGWzDtblC6WRg1P1ew=

Terraform failed to load the default state from the "s3" backend.
State migration cannot occur unless the state can be loaded. Backend
modification and state migration has been aborted. The state in both the
source and the destination remain unmodified. Please resolve the
above error and try again.
```

It seems that `terraform` tries to load state from `s3` bucket rather than push to `s3` bucket. How can I configure `terraform` to push state to s3?

I have configured aws profile on a tf file:

```
provider "aws" {
  region  = "ap-southeast-2"
  profile = "me"
}
```

The credential for the current user has admin permission on the bucket.

Comment: Did you checked the permissions of the user that you're using to run terraform?

Comment: Terraform normally first check if the state exists, if it doesn't exist it will create a new one.  n the case it is trying to reach the s3 bucket to check if the state exists and apparently are not being able to.

Comment: I am using admin user which has permission to write to the bucket.

Answer (score 2):

I was facing the same issue and the found like the bucket mentioned in the backend.tf file was not created in my aws console. Hence I create the bucket with the same bucket name mentioned in the backend.tf file and it worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

For further readers:

AWS credentials can be provided As @Thiago Arrais mentioned

Another way to provide credentials in `backend` block is to define profile:

```
terraform {
  backend "s3" {
    profile = "me" <-- aws profile
    bucket  = "MY_BUCKET"
    key     = "tfstate"
    region  = "ap-southeast-2"
  }
}
```

And your `~/.aws/credentails` file has profile `me` with `AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID` and `AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY` defined in it as follows:

```
[me]
AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID = access_key_value
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY = secret_key_value
```

I had exact same problem. When `terraform {backend "s3" {}}` is defined then that block is evaluated before `provider "aws" {}` block. That's why backend cannot find credentials info defined in provider block.

Answer (score 0):

You're not providing the S3 credentials in the backend block. You'll need to set them there (`access_key` and `secret_key` parameters) or via environment variables (`AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID` and `AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY`).

You'll also need to make sure that the bucket exists and that these credentials do have access to it.

*By the way, you don't need an AWS provider block. The S3 backend is usable even if you don't manage AWS resources in your Terraform config.*

Answer (score 0):

For me I was having different aws region in backend.tf than where my bucket was.